# How to use boost preprocessor to easier gcc neon inline assesmbly?

Tags: c-preprocessor, inline-assembly, c99

While coding gcc neon inline assembler, usually have to write very long clobber if use a lot of registers. How to write a macro to list serials of register in the clobber section? better use boost preprocessor. Thanks.

Current method:

```
__asm(
  "mov r0, #0\n"
  "mov r1, #1\n"
  "mov r2, #2\n"
  "mov r3, #3\n"
  :
  :
  : "r0", "r1", "r2", "r3"
)
```

Better way:

```
__asm(
  "mov r0, #0\n"
  "mov r1, #1\n"
  "mov r2, #2\n"
  "mov r3, #3\n"
  :
  :
  : MACRO_RANGE(r, 0, 3)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it as below:

// build string

#define __asmpp_str(x) #x

#define asmpp_xstr(x) __asmpp_str(x)

#define __asmpp_reg_str_list(z, regNumber, regPrefix) asmpp_xstr( regPrefix ## regNumber ) BOOST_PP_COMMA()
#define asmpp_reg_str_list(regPrefix, first, last) BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO(first, last, __asmpp_reg_str_list, regPrefix) asmpp_xstr( regPrefix ## last)

__asm(

"mov r0, #0\n"

"mov r1, #1\n"

"mov r2, #2\n"

"mov r3, #3\n"

:

:

: asmpp_reg_str_list(r, 0, 3)

)